# Can I say "a fitting meaning"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it grammatically correct to say "I've checked online dictionaries, but can't find **a fitting meaning**"?

I've searched the Internet for the phrase, but it doesn't seem like it's being used.

Comment: What's wrong with "appropriate meaning"? I would use "fitting" after "meaning". E.g. "This meaning is fitting for his purpose."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the -ed particple "fitted" suggests that someone fits meanings to words.  The use of passive participles or the passive voice implies the meaning was fitted *by somebody*.

A "fitted suit" is one that a tailor has made to fit you perfectly. A suit that fits may have been bought off the peg, but just happens to match your size.

So "fitted meaning" is not correct.

Instead a relative clause is better (if unsure about participle or relative clause, chose the relative clause).

> I can't find a meaning that fits.